# Why does the trainable variables in actor not have gradients?

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I implement ddpg in tensorflow myself, and I run into a mysterious bug, which takes me several days to think but still no result.

I define the actor loss as

```
actor_loss = - tf.reduce_mean(self.critic_with_actor.Q)
```

where `self.critic_with_actor.Q` are the output of the `critic` which takes as one of its inputs action obtained from `actor`. The problem is, The `actor` somehow doesn't receive any gradient. Here's a snapshot of the related tensorboard info:
[image]

where `Tanh` is the output tensor of the `actor`, i.e. the `action` selected by the `actor`. `BiasAdd` is the input tensor to `Tanh`, the others are just trainable variables in `actor`. As you can see, there are gradients for `Tanh`, but not for the others.
here's the architecture of my main actor-critic network
[image]

where `critic_1` correspond to `self.critic_with_actor` in code, which shares variables with `critic`.

Here's my code https://github.com/xlnwel/ddpg-bipedal/blob/f1f6ed8842f7f13254f77ff37d9d0d340a4650e0/tensorflow-imp/ddpg_tf.py#L37-L41. The code should be able to run (as the readme.md suggests) even though the bug exists.

Comment: Can you narrow down your problem to a smaller example?